# What would be the best approach to normalise data for an LSTM model (using Tensorflow) with this wide range of values?

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, machine-learning, normalization

I am new to machine learning so still trying to wrap my head around concepts, please bear this in mind if my question may not be as concise as needed.

I am building a Tensorflow JS model with LSTM layers for time-series prediction (RNN).

The dataset used is pinged every few hundred milliseconds (at random intervals). However, the data produced can come in very wide ranges e.g. Majority of data received will be of value 20, 40, 45 etc. However sometimes this value will reach 75,000 at the extreme end.

So the data range is between 1 to 75,000.

When I normalise this data using a standard min/max method to produce a value between 0-1, the normalised data for the majority of data requests will be to many small significant decimal places. e.g.: '0.0038939328722009236'

So my question(s) are:

1) Is this min/max the best approach for normalising this type of data?

2) Will the RNN model work well with so many significant decimal places and precision?

3) Should I also be normalising the output label? (of which there will be 1 output)

**Update**

I have just discovered a very good resource on a google quick course, that delves into preparing data for ML. One technique suggested would be to 'clip' the data at the extremes. Thought I would add it here for reference: https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/data-prep

Comment: Is the data smoothly moving up and down? If so, you can consider your X to be (T(n) - T(n-1)), i.e. train and predict the gradient not the real value, after prediction the gradient you can add it with the previous value to achieve the next value.

Comment: No unfortunately, it is quite random although as time progresses the values will increase on average. But it could be any value between that range at any point.
Is it not a good idea to train/predict on specific values then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing a bit more research I think I have a decent solution now;

I will be performing two steps, with the first being to use 'quantile bucketing' (or sometimes called 'binning' ref: https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/data-prep/transform/bucketing).

Effectively it involves splitting the range of values down into smaller subset ranges, and applying an integer value to each smaller range of values. e.g. A initial range of 1 to 1,000,000 could be broken down into ranges of 100k. So 1 to 100,000 would be range number 1, 100,001 to 200,000 would be range number 2.

In order to have an even distribution of samples within each bucket range, due to the skewed dataset I have, I modify the subset ranges so they capture roughly the same samples in each 'bucket' range. For example, the first range of the example above, could be 1 to 1,000 instead of 1 to 100,000. The next bucket range would be 1,001 to 2,000. The third could be 2,001 to 10,000 and so on..

In my use case I ended up with 22 different bucket ranges. The next step is my own adaptation, since I don't want to have 22 different features (as seems to be suggested in the link). Instead, I apply the standard min/max scaling to these bucket ranges, resulting in the need for only 1 feature. This gives me the final result of normalised data between 0 and 1, which perfectly deals with my skewed dataset.

Now the lowest normalised value I get (other than 0) is 0.05556.

Hope this helps others.